# want to redirect an html page as sub page of other page

Tags: html, .htaccess

Like in wordpress you can make a page as sub page of other page how can we do it with HTML files with the help of `.htaccess`?
I have HTML pages on my website like this

abc.com/1.html and abc.com/2.html

I want to remove the `.html` extention like this

abc.com/1 and abc.com/2

And I want abc.com/2 to redirect to

abc.com/1/2  Please do remember the 1 in this url is not a folder.Both these urls abc.com/1 and abc.com/2 are in the same folder.

How can I do it.

Comment: You want a .htaccess solution right?

Comment: yes I want .htaccess solution, like in wordpress you can make a page as sub page of other page how can we do it with html files with the help of .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

To mask the file extensions, first enable `MultiViews` into your VirtualHost configuration file or `.htaccess`:

```
Options +MultiViews
```

Then, you could just provide hyperlinks without the `.html` extension. The HTTP server will search for file by adding extension itself. But you can also add a rewrite rule in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301]
```

Here you get the `%{THE_REQUEST}` and parse it to rewrite URL without the `.html` at the end of the filename.

To redirect `1/2/` to `2/`:

```
RewriteRule ^1/2/(.*)$ 2/$1
```

Please note that in this second rule, you do not use the `[R]` flag because you do not want to change URL in the browser.

Be sure to enable `RewriteEngine` before using rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

For more information about URL rewriting: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html

Answer (score 0):

In order to use regex better to use mod_rewrite which is more powerful than mod_alias.

## Turn mod_rewrite on

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^answer-now(/.*|)$ http://www.abc..net/2/? [L,NC,R=301]
```